# Local sections of an etale space form a base for the bundle space

Tags: general-topology

An etale space is a bundle $p: E \rightarrow X$ that is a local homeomorphism. Now I'm trying to understand the following claim: the images of the local sections $s: U \rightarrow E$ form a base for the topology on the total space $E$.

Now I understand that the projection map and local sections are open maps, so that they map open sets to open sets. Thus if I $V \subset E$ open, I know that $p(V)$  will be open and $p^{-1}|_V$ is a section of $p$. However, I'm not sure how to show that $V$ can be written as a union of images of sections. One thing I thought was that $s(p^{-1}(V)) \subset V$ for some section $s$ but not sure how to continue.

Comment: You need to use that you have a local homeomorphism.

Comment: What is $p^{-1} \mid_V$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That $p$ is a local homeomorphism means that each $x \in E$ has an open neigborhood $V \subset E$ which is mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto an open $U \subset B$. Call such $V$ *nice* and let $p_V : V \to U$ denote the restriction of $p$.

Each nice $V$ gives therefore a local section $s_V : U \to E$; simply define $s_V(y) = (p_V)^{-1}(y) \in V \subset E$.

Clearly all open subsets $W \subset V$ of a nice $V$ are nice. Now let $O \subset E$ be open and $x \in O$. Let $V$ be a nice neigborhood of $x$ and $W = O \cap V$. Then $W$ is nice and it is the image of the local section $s_W$ associated to $W$. Thus $O$ is the union of images of local sections.